# Spark gives InvalidProtocolBufferException when querying Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Running this example in the Spark (0.9.1) shell on the Hadoop 2 namenode

```
scala> val file1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://testhadoopname1.myserver.com:9000/user/ubuntu/events/datepart=2014-04-11/2014-04-11-09-42.txt")
```

```
14/04/16 10:27:01 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(74968) called with curMem=302142, maxMem=311387750
14/04/16 10:27:01 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values to memory (estimated size 73.2 KB, free 296.6 MB)
file1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MappedRDD[7] at textFile at :12
```

```
scala> file1.count()
```

Why do I get this?

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).; Host Details : local host is: "testhadoopname1.myserver.com/10.255.187.229"; destination host is: "testhadoopname1.myserver.com":9000;
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1679)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatusInternal(FileSystem.java:1701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:726)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:15)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:20)
    at $iwC$$iwC.(:22)
    at $iwC.(:24)
    at (:26)
    at .(:30)
    at .()
    at .(:7)
    at .()
    at $print()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1040)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:604)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:793)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:838)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:750)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:598)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:608)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:931)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:881)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:973)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1487)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:200)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:241)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.parseDelimitedFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:891)
```

Comment: Can you post your code? How are you using the Protocol Buffer? Are you passing an empty / 0 length array?

Comment: Can you confirm the port is 9000? Maybe it should be 8020.

Comment: Confirmed that port is 9000. If changed to anything else, I receive connection refused errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that I was on a unqualified version of Hadoop (2.0.3-alpha build). I recreated the HDFS cluster on the latest Hadoop 2.3.0 with Spark 0.9.1 standalone clustermanager and ran the above example in the spark-shell..... works just as advertised.